# Scanner nextInt() doesn't return all integers in string?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a string `currLine = "0   1435     " 3029 "      "(1975.92)" " 72,304""` (there are quotations within the string) and I want to print out all of the integers in currLine. But with the code below, I only get the number 0 printed out. How do I use nextInt() so that it prints out all of the integers?

```
        Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(currLine);           
        while (scanLine.hasNext()) {
            if (scanLine.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println(scanLine.nextInt());
            }
            scanLine.next();
        }
```

Comment: Do you want it to print 0, 1, 4, 3, 5, ... or 0, 1435, 3029, ...

Comment: I want it to print 0, 1435, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as the `Scanner` encounters something that isn't an int, `hasNextInt()` returns `false`. Not to mention the fact that you're skipping over some valid ints with the `scanLine.next()` call at the bottom of your `while`-loop. You can use a `Matcher` instead:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(currLine);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

```
0
1435
3029
1975
92
72
304
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `else` word is missing too. No need to do `next()` if `nextInt()` done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **next()** goes until it sees a space.  I would use **replace("\"","")**, rinse and repeat with other characters until you have a string of the integers you can print.